# PL/SQL function count users

Tags: oracle, plsql

i need to count all the users using pl/sql.
I have error ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

```
 FUNCTION calculeaza_total_utilizatori RETURN NUMBER IS
        numar NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT  count (idutilizator)  into numar from utilizator;
        RETURN numar;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Nu sunt utilizatori');
    END;
```

What can I do? Thank you

Comment: I would first try the SQL (without the INTO clause) as a standalone statement to see if the error is there.  Also, your PL/SQL to create the function should have 'CREATE OR REPLACE' before the function definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use the [CREATE FUNCTION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_function.htm) statement?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculeaza_total_utilizatori RETURN NUMBER IS
...
```